# Keep track of progress of a `map`

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have a `map` operation (that is actually run in parallel using `parMap` from `Control.Parallel.Strategies`) that takes quite a while. Given that I know how many times the function is applied (`n` in this context), how can I easily display, every once in a while, how many of the `n` applications have been evaluated?

The obvious solution would be to make the map a `mapM` with some `putStr` inside the mapping function, but that would:

- take an unnecessary amount of efficiency
- not sample the status every once in a while but in every applications
- basically remove all the good things about a deterministic algorithm in the context of parallelism

So, is there a way to keep track of this information, that I'm missing, that avoids these problems?

Comment: Aside from apparently meaning "championships" in Romanian, what does "campionate" mean?

Comment: You may want to look at the `monad-par` package. It doesn't seem to quite go where you're looking, but `Control.Monad.Par.IO` may ease the pain a bit. It's conceivable that you could hook into the sort of goo that makes ThreadScope go, but I doubt that will give you quite what you want. Another option might be to use something horrible and unsafe like `trace` or `unsafePerformIO` to let threads report completion. I think the essential problem is that "has such-and-such a thread finished yet?" is not a question that makes sense in a pure context.

Comment: You should add `parMap`'s type, or mention if it's from `Control.Parallel.Strategies`.

Comment: @dfeuer Woops. I meant "sample" I guess.

Comment: @Zeta I have just realised that `parMap` is unnecessary. For the sake of the discussion it's equal to `map`.

Comment: @Jefffrey: So, for the sake of discussion, a `mapWithCounter :: NFData b => _ -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> IO [b]` would be fine? I have an idea, but I'm gone for the rest of the day.

Comment: You wrote that the whole map operation takes a while. Is this because of the high number of elements in the list or does each mapped function take long?

Comment: @j.p. Actually both. The initial list is long N (with N very long), the operation on each element of this list generates a list of N elements too (so the idea it to generate a matrix out of a list). And the computation of this list for every element is relatively expensive.

Comment: I also have another instance where I just map over a N^2 list performing relatively simple tasks on each element.

Comment: @Zeta That would be equivalent to a `mapM` in the sense that suddenly we are introducing `IO` and losing the benefits of pure code. Or maybe I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: @Jefffrey: No, you understand perfectly fine. Displaying the status every once in a while necessarily leads to `IO`. It's exactly what dfeuer mentioned. The "how-much-has-my-map-finished?" question cannot really get answered in pure code.

Comment: @Zeta, in principle, it would be possible to set up the runtime system to allow these threads to be tagged when sparked (using a version of `par` that takes a tag), and then to offer IO actions to get information about just the threads that have a certain tag. But this would probably be a bit tricky to do efficiently, and as far as I can tell, GHC just doesn't offer anything remotely like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production you probably shouldn't use trace and are forced to deal with the complications of needing IO, but for tests you could modify the definition of parMap to take another parameter telling when to emit a count:

```
import Control.Monad (sequence)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies (Strategy, using, rseq, rparWith, parMap)
import Debug.Trace (traceShow)
import System.IO (hFlush, hSetBuffering, BufferMode(NoBuffering), stdout)

evalList' :: Integer -> Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
evalList' t s as = sequence $ foldr f [] $ zip as [1..]
  where f (a, n) ss | n `mod` t == 0 = s (traceShow n a):ss
                    | otherwise      = s a:ss

parList' :: Integer -> Strategy a -> Strategy [a]
parList' t s = evalList' t (rparWith s)

parMap' :: Integer -> Strategy b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
parMap' t s f xs = map f xs `using` parList' t s

-- some work to do
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib(n-2)

main = do hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
          print $ sum (parMap' 1000 rseq (fib.(+20).(`mod` 5)) ([1..10000]::[Integer]))
```

If the work packages given by each list element become to small, you could adapt parListChunk instead accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One could try to craft this behaviour using [timeout](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/System-Timeout.html#v:timeout).

```
seconds :: Int
seconds = 1000000

progress :: [a] -> IO ()
progress [] = return ()
progress l@(x:xs) =
  do r <- timeout (5 * seconds) x  -- 5s
     threadDelay (2 * seconds)     -- 2s more delay
     case r of
       Nothing -> progress l  -- retry
       Just y  -> do putStrLn "one done!"
                     progress xs
```

Be careful since I fear that `timeout` is aborting the computation. If there's another thread that evaluates `x` that should be fine, but if this is the only thread doing that it could cause a livelock if 5 seconds are not enough.